# Unable to split data

Tags: python

I have a data like below:

```
data = """1000
2000
3000

4000

5000
6000

7000
8000
9000

10000"""
```

Now, I want to sum up the elements that appear before the space and maintain the `max_sum` track with the sum of the next elements that appear before the empty line. So for me, it should be the sum of `1000,2000,3000 = 6000` compared with the initial max_sum for eg `0`, and now sum the next element i.e `4000`, and keep comparing with the max_sum which could be like `max(6000, 4000) = 6000` and keep on doing the same but need to reset the sum if I encounter a empty line.

Below is my code:

```
max_num = 0
    sum = 0
    for line in data:
        # print(line)
        sum = sum + int(line)
        if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
            sum=0
        max_num = max(max_num, sum)
```

This gives an error:

```
sum = sum + int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *int()* is impervious to leading and trailing whitespace - e.g., *int('\n99\n')* will result in 99 without error. However, a string comprised entirely of whitespace will result in ValueError. That's what is happening here. You're trying to parse a string that just contains a newline character.

You can take advantage of ValueError for these data as follows:

```
data = """1000
2000
3000

4000

5000
6000

7000
8000
9000

10000"""

current_sum = 0
max_sum = float('-inf')

for t in data.splitlines():
    try:
        x = int(t)
        current_sum += x
    except ValueError:
        max_sum = max(max_sum, current_sum)
        current_sum = 0

print(f'Max sum = {max(max_sum, current_sum)}')
```

**Output:**

```
Max sum = 24000
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast empty lines to int:

```
max_num = 0
sum = 0
for line in data:
    print(line)
    if line.strip():
        sum = sum + int(line)
    if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        sum=0
    max_num = max(max_num, sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick oneliner:

```
data = """1000
2000
3000

4000

5000
6000

7000
8000
9000

10000"""

max(
    sum(
        int(i) for i in l.split('\n')
    ) for l in data.split('\n\n')
)
```

which gives `24000`

First it divides based on `\n\n` and then based on `\n`. Sums all elements in the groups and then chooses the biggest value.

Comment: It gives me this error `int(i) for i in l.split('\n')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '    '`

Comment: @RushHour That's because you're trying to convert spaces to int. But you said yourself there are no spaces in the input.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use builtin names like `sum`, here you need to split the data in `\n` you will get list then you can loop over and remove space using `strip()` then if line has some digits it will sum it else it will assign 0.

```
max_num = 0
sum_val = 0


for line in data.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()
    sum_val = int(line) + sum_val if line and line.isdigit() else 0
    max_num = max(max_num, sum_val)
print(max_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lines that are just composed of '\n', which you are trying to convert into int.
You should move your test for line up the `int` conversion, and `continue` without casting to int if the line is '\n' or '\r\n'

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
data = """1000
    2000
    3000
    
    4000
    
    5000
    6000
    
    7000
    8000
    9000
    
    10000
    """

data = data.splitlines()

max_sum = 0
group = []

for data_index, single_data in enumerate(data):
    single_data = single_data.replace(" ","")
    if single_data == "":
        if max_sum < sum(group):
            max_sum = sum(group)
        group = []
    else:
        group.append(int(single_data))

print(max_sum)
```

Output:

```
24000
```